# Как перевести строки через пробел в массив

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки

Например, есть такая строка: '12 13'.

Мне надо создать массив с элементами из строки так, чтобы элементами оказались подстроки, разделённые пробелом.

Например: из строки '12 13' сделать массив ['12', '13'].

Answer (score 6):

Используйте метод `split()` объектов `str`.

```py
S.split(sep=None, maxsplit=-1) -> list of strings
```

```css
    Return a list of the words in S, using sep as the
    delimiter string.  If maxsplit is given, at most maxsplit
    splits are done. If sep is not specified or is None, any
    whitespace string is a separator and empty strings are
    removed from the result.
```

---

Если вы хотите, чтобы результатирующий список состоял из строк:

```py
message = '12 13 14 88 16'
result = message.split()
```

`result`:

```py
['12', '13', '14', '88', '16']
```

---

Или если вы хотите, чтобы числа преобразовывались в `int`:

```py
message = '12 13 14 88 16'
result = list(map(int, message.split()))
```

`result`:

```
[12, 13, 14, 88, 16]
```

Comment: в сплите пробел по умолчанию, можно не писать

Comment: @splash58 Да, но для наглядности лучше указать.

Comment: `result = message.split()`
or
`result = list(map(int, message.split()))`

Comment: и там, и там `message.split()` оже самое что `message.split(' ')`

Comment: Разница есть (пусть и не не на таких входных данных) и существенная.
`'1  2\n3  '.split()` -> `['1', '2', '3']` и `'1  2\n3  '.split(' ')` -> `['1', '', '2\n3', '', '']`

Comment: @extrn Согласен, но в данной систуации, я считаю, было более наглядно явно указать пробел. Тогда при изучении кода автором, возможно, ему станет более ясно, как работает `split`, ведь в будущем, если понадобится опять разделить строку, он может не догадаться, что там вообще существует такой аргумент, как сепаратор.

Comment: Я не критикую ваш выбор. И у `split` есть еще один необязательный параметр - `maxsplit=-1` :)